# Remove required all attribute in the form if any on of the form-group is valid

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I have been working on the requirement there are multiple form-groups in my form when any one of the form-group is valid remaining all form-groups required attribute should be removed. why because in that form any one of the uer is enough.

```
   <form id="inviteTeamForm">
  <div class="form-group">
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control"/>
<span class="CstErrInvite">Field is required</span>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" value="" />
<span class="CstErrInvite">Field is required</span>
</div>
<div>
<input type='email' name="email" id="email" placeholder="Company email" class="form-control email" size="10" />
<span class="CstErrMsg">Field is required</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control"/>
<span class="CstErrInvite">Field is required</span>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" value="" />
<span class="CstErrInvite">Field is required</span>
</div>
<div>
<input type='email' name="email" id="email" placeholder="Company email" class="form-control email" size="10" />
<span class="CstErrMsg">Field is required</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control"/>
<span class="CstErrInvite">Field is required</span>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" value="" />
<span class="CstErrInvite">Field is required</span>
</div>
<div>
<input type='email' name="email" id="email" placeholder="Company email" class="form-control email" size="10" />
<span class="CstErrMsg">Field is required</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control"/>
<span class="CstErrInvite">Field is required</span>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" value="" />
<span class="CstErrInvite">Field is required</span>
</div>
<div>
<input type='email' name="email" id="email" placeholder="Company email" class="form-control email" size="10" />
<span class="CstErrMsg">Field is required</span>
</div>
</div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="inviteUser">Invite </button>
</form>
    <script>
       $("#inviteTeamForm").submit(function(){
        var formElements = $("form-group").closet();
        if(formElements.valid()){
            formElements.next.find.required = false;
        }
       })
    </script>

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: initially i want to load 'required' attribute to all the inputs.

Comment: You have a typo in your js `$("form-group").closet();`, I'm pretty sure it is **`.closest()`**, with two `s` letters

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#inviteUser").click(function() {
  var sumVal = "";
  $("#inviteTeamForm").find(".form-group").each(function() {
    var $this = this;

    $($this).find("input").each(function() {
      sumVal += $(this).val();
      if ($(this).val()) {
        $($this).addClass("req-validate");
        return false;
      } else {
        $($this).removeClass("req-validate");
      }
    });

    $(".form-group.req-validate")
      .find("input")
      .attr("required", true);

    $(".form-group")
      .not(".req-validate")
      .find("input")
      .removeAttr("required");
  });

  if (!sumVal) {
    console.log(sumVal)
    $(".form-group")
      .find("input")
      .attr("required", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="inviteTeamForm">
  <div class="form-group" id="group1">
    <div class="required">
      <input type="text" x-moz-errormessage="Enter firstName" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="required">
      <input type="text" x-moz-errormessage="Enter lastName" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" value="" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="required">
      <input type='email' x-moz-errormessage="Enter your company email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Company email" class="form-control email" size="10" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="group2">
    <div class="required">
      <input type="text" x-moz-errormessage="Enter firstName" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="required">
      <input type="text" x-moz-errormessage="Enter lastName" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" value="" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="required">
      <input type='email' x-moz-errormessage="Enter your company email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Company email" class="form-control email" value="" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="group3">
    <div class="required">
      <input type="text" x-moz-errormessage="Enter firstName" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="required">
      <input type="text" x-moz-errormessage="Enter lastName" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" value="" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="required">
      <input type='email' x-moz-errormessage="Enter your company email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Company email" class="form-control email" size="10" value="" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="group4">
    <div class="required">
      <input type="text" x-moz-errormessage="Enter firstName" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="required">
      <input type="text" x-moz-errormessage="Enter lastName" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" value="" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="required">
      <input type='email' x-moz-errormessage="Enter your company email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Company email" class="form-control email" size="10" value="" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="inviteUser">Invite </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Erdogan thank you for your answer, but iam not using jquery validator iam just using html5 required without validator i hve to do it

Comment: So what is `.valid()` ? i think this jquery validate prototype ?

Comment: yes this is working it's disturbing my UI and i don't want to show this field is required it should show like html5 required. why because i used already setCustomValidity method in my global js file can you help me

Comment: @ramuramu I remove `jquery-validate` in my answer try again, please.

Comment: querySelectorAll() doesn't work in old browers right?

Comment: @ramuramu check this page https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

Comment: when i enter firstName in the second row it should show that current row email should be show html5 validation. lastname is not mandatory. the same thing should for all rows. if i don't enter any thing in the second row it should not show any validation. form should be submitted.

Comment: Hi Erdogan Oksuz, i removed required attribute placed custom erro message . how to change code now can you help me